# Acceptable tension on copper piping?

Tags: plumbing, copper, gap, blocking

Earlier this week I had a plumber rough in valve/piping for a shower renovation. Since then, I have decided to go back and redo the walls (long, long story) and, as a result, the final finished wall will be 1/4" thinner. I know for a fact that this change will leave the nipple of the tub spout exposed by roughly that difference. The shower valve *should* be ok, but I won't know for sure until tiling is complete.

Rather than calling the plumber back to redo the spout (and possibly the entire valve!), I would like to place 1/4" shims behind the straps that are securing the pipes to the blocking. My question is this: Can the copper pipes and soldered joints handle the ***very*** slight amount of pressure needed to shim the plumbing back that 1/4" or is it essential that the plumbing is secured as it would normally rest?

Comment: I'm sure it had just as much stress on it when it was shimmed and clamped.  1/4" over 2-3ft is almost nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You are fine.  Copper is pretty pliable and one soft metal.  I am assuming that this branch is already working and capped.  So if you do have any issues you should know right away.  Also I would tell the plumber what you did so he isn't pulling out his hair if something goes wrong.